# Kernel Density Estimation for non-parametric

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I'm writing an R function to get the fitted values of the kernel density estimate. For that I use the computational formula of summation of ({n-1 h-1 K{(x - Xi)/h}}?)
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \frac1{n h}\sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)
$$ where $n$ is the number of observations and $h$ is the bandwidth. Here $K$ is supposed to be the kernel function, but I don't find a clear formula to plug-in for $K$ in this formula.

I'm known that there are various kernel functions, but I clearly couldn't find the list of kernel functions that exist. (Epanechnikov kernel, cosine, Gaussian, Parzen, rectangular, and triangle kernels are among).

Could someone kindly provide me with a/some straightforward formulas to obtain K?

I used the following article:

[DENSITY ESTIMATION FOR STATISTICS AND DATA
ANALYSIS
B.W. Silverman
School of Mathematics University of Bath, UK](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/paper.pdf).

Comment: Well, you really need to learn $\LaTeX$ (and its version implemented here in Mathjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  As for me doing it, lack of parenthesis makes the intention unclear to me, so will not try. At least edit to make the meaning of the formals clear!

Comment: I guessed that you want formula 2.2a from the linked paper. Can you verify? Also, now push the *edit* button, look at the $\LaTeX$, and learn!

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) is a list of common kernel functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is just something you pick as part of the model. The standard choices are indeed Gaussian, Epanechnikov, rectangular, etc. Exactly which properties $K$ needs to satisfy will depend on what properties you want, but the general baseline is just that:

- $\int K(x) \, dx = 1$ so that the overall estimate integrates to 1;
- *usually* $K(x) \ge 0$ so that, combined with the previous one, the overall estimate is a valid density;
- *usually* $K(-x) = K(x)$ for simplicity.

You're not going to be able to write all of this in your code, but you can implement the most common ones and possibly allow for a user-specified one in some way.

@user20160 posted [a useful catalog of the most common choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) while I was writing this.